# SQL Server : large DB Query In Chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I have minimal expertise in SQL Server but I have used MySQL in the past and pretty good at it.

My question is: I have a rather large database with over 130m+ records.

I wish to only get the URL column but every single record in this column.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio jams up when saving to a file due to one error or another so I have come to the conclusion that I need to do this in chunks.

I am running this command at the moment and saving to file

```
SELECT TOP 20000000 [URL] 
FROM [dbo].[siteentry] 
WHERE [Content] LIKE ''
```

However when this command finishes I have 0 clue how to skip the first 20,000,000 and continue onto the next batch of 20,000,000 without killing the server.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With SQL Server **2012**, you can use the `OFFSET...FETCH` commands:

```
SELECT [URL] 
FROM [dbo].[siteentry] 
WHERE [Content] LIKE '' 
ORDER BY (some column)
    OFFSET 20000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY
```

For this to work, you **must** order by some column in your table - which you should *anyway*, since a `TOP ....` without an `ORDER BY` is useless - you'll get back arbitrary rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "offset" to skip the rows. Check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a text file containing all urls, then I suggest you to use [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.100).aspx) command line utility:

```
bcp "SELECT url FROM [dbo].[siteentry] WHERE [Content] LIKE ''" queryout  Output.txt -S Server -T -d DatabaseName -c
```

It will generate the file at once, no need to split it in chunks, and you won't get annoying out of memory errors from SSMS

Comment: Oh perfect let me research this method. Thanks