# SQL Query inside a C# For Loop

Tags: c#, sql

I'm creating a simple C# programs to compare a bunch of log files with our SQL Server, to see which has been processed or not.

The issue is the following:

The SQL has more than 2.000.000. So, only a SELECT would take too much time to load.

My ideia is the following: I have a custom object that loads all the data from the logs and them, a FOR Loop would search for a match inside the SQL. It's happening that it won't find any matches with the Query into the For.
I've already tried the SELECT * FROM, but there are too many registers to load that way.

This is my C# Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < registros.Count; i++) {
    command = new($"Select DateTime, P15, Reference from ProductionDay where DateTime = Convert(datetime, '{registros[i].day.Year}-{registros[i].day.Day}-{registros[i].day.Month}')", cnn);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{i:D5} - Editing {registros[i].part_number}");
    
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {

            Console.WriteLine("SQL Matched!");

            try {
                if (reader["Reference"].ToString().Trim() == registros[i].part_number) {

                    registros[i].sql_part_number = registros[i].part_number;

                    registros[i].quantity += Convert.ToInt32(reader["P15"].ToString());
                }

            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code only writes `SQL Matched!` in the last itineration of the loop.

Is this the best way to do a QUERY Loop? I'm learning now about C# and SQL connections.

Comment: You should avoid empty `try-catches`.

Comment: Yes... I'm using to try to debug the code. It's removed after using.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't filter this database side? You already have a WHERE clause.

Comment: Does your DateTime have a time component?  If so, it wouldn't be equal.

Comment: As an aside: empty try-catches are too easy to accidentally leave in, it's probably a good idea to wean yourself off those. In VS, consider using Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings and checking the "break when thrown" box for CLR exceptions. That way you still stop at the earliest place if an error happens, but without the risk of leaving in "error handling" that sweeps everything under the rug and leaves even harder to diagnose failures.

Comment: Filtering on the client, rather than in a WHERE clause will be slower than letting the db do the work. Also, look up the column numbers for "Reference" and "P15" before you start, then access the data by _ordinal_ (column number) rather than column name

Comment: @LarsTech this is it man! Changed the Search to ````DateTime >= Convert(datetime, '{registros[i].day.Year}-{registros[i].day.Day}-{registros[i].day.Month} 00:00:00') AND DateTime <= Convert(datetime, '{registros[i].day.Year}-{registros[i].day.Day}-{registros[i].day.Month} 23:59:59')```` and now the search goes normally.

Comment: [Use Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine)

Comment: Note that both C# and T-SQL have ways to coerce a full DateTime to a date (zero-ing out the time component). Do that and you can compare for equality

Comment: Please describe the task you are trying to solve. What kind of records do ou have in DB, what records are in the file(s). How are you going to correlate (basically, what is the key?) the record in DB with the record in file? I really doubt it can be done by looping through 2M lines in files and then search the corresponding one in DB. But if you provide more details then I'm sure the solution will be found much faster.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to full load the table, can you try query in chunk? It will reduce the stress, also you can preserve memory for further processing. Try to query on server side too to help not transferring everything at once to client side (I got this from Postgresql, I think SQL Server also support this)

There is an example for this:
[SQL Server : large DB Query In Chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601939/sql-server-large-db-query-in-chunks)